# Multiple GNSS receivers on a tiny PCB - layout advices

Tags: rf, design, layout, pcb-layers, gnss

I am designing a board where I want to have 2 receivers using different constellations.

Due to space constraints, I have the idea to put the two receivers on the same PCB (one on the top layer and one on the bottom layer).
Concerning the layer stackup, I think I'll go for a 6 layers.

The stackup would be like this:

- Option 1

```
Layer 1: Top components (LNA and filters) + 1st GNSS receiver 
(Prepreg)
Layer 2: RF GND n°1 
(Prepreg)
Layer 3: VCC plane 
(Core)
Layer 4: VCC plane 
(Prepreg)
Layer 5: RF GND n°2
(Prepreg)
Layer 6: 2nd receiver, RF tracks
```

So each receiver will have his own PDN...

But I have in mind the 2nd layer stackup, where I would use just one LDO... (I'm thinking about the thermal management of the PCB)

or

- Option 2

```
Layer 1: Top components (LNA and filters) + 1st receiver 
(prepreg)
Layer 2: RF GND  n°1
(Core)
Layer 3: VCC plane 
(Prepreg)
Layer 4: GND plane 
(Core)
Layer 5: RF GND 
(Pregreg)
Layer 6: 2nd receiver, RF tracks
```

Concerning the material, I would choose FR4 rather than Rodgers for cost reduction (I have no distributed components).

The architecture of the global system would be:
Filter->LNA->splitter-> 1st receiver & 2nd receiver

The thing is that I'm worried about the vias and the impedance. The via brings impedance miss-matches (discontinuities). So maybe it will cause some problems especially for the 2nd receiver...

Do you have any advice to give me regarding my layer stackup?
And for the layout, what things do I have to care about?